# Using injected from controller in view in angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to use injected into controller modules in the view directly without binding it to controller explicitly? In other words, is there something along the lines of

```
<p>{{$ctrl.$injectedIntoThisController.$stateParams.name}}<p>
```

for when $stateParams is injected into controller?

Comment: helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a service without injecting it, you can use the `$injector` service to inject services dinamically based on a condition and then bind what you need to the view.

```
angular.controller('MyCtrl', ['$injector', function($injector){

 if(something){
  var service = $injector.get('MyService');
  this.prop = service.prop;
 }

}])
```

and in your view bind the property.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">
 <p>{{$ctrl.prop}}<p>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector